# Discord.js and quick.db data not found error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

It is a topic opened by making use of translation.

The part that gives the error without giving the whole code is as follows:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = async(message,guild,args,member) => {

//console.log(guild,message)
const db = require('quick.db');

const d2 = db.fetch(`dil_${message.guild.id}`);
var lang;
if(!d2) {
lang = require('../lang/tr.json');
} else {
if(d2 == "tr") {
 lang = require('../lang/tr.json');
} else {
    if(d2 == "en") {
        lang = require('../lang/en.json');
    }
}
    }
 }
```

[the error i got:][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilaQs.png

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```js
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();
```

at the top of the file and remove the following:

```js
const db = require ('quick.db');
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Comment: What's your quick.db version, @DnzCgn?

Comment: my Quick.db version is ^9.0.5